# determine .class name using DOMNodeInserted

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, mutation-events

If i run this below:

```
$(document).bind('DOMNodeInserted', function(){

      $('.new', this).hide();
});
```

it will run ok and it will hide the .new div. But i need to do something like the below:

```
$(document).bind('DOMNodeInserted', function(){

          // if class .new exists
          // do something to the other elements e.g (body, #div, h1, h2, etc) not to .new class
});
```

many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just check the length of `.new`, and handle it as follows:

```
$(document).bind('DOMNodeInserted', function(){
    if($('.new').length > 0)
    {
        $('body *').not('.new').hide();
    }
});
```

See this [jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8mxee/)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$(document).bind('DOMNodeInserted', function () {    
    if ($('.new').length) {
        // if class .new exists
        // do something to the other elements e.g (body, #div, h1, h2, etc) not to .new class
    }
});
```